# How to upload Certificate in Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a certificate in my local machine so when i am Deploying my project locally it is working fine but when I am deploying it on Azure Cluster it is showing error Because the node in azure cluster dont have those certificates.

How to overcome this problem.

Comment: Just to clarfy, you are talking about client certificates used to upload your app to cluster? Or you are uploading http app to cluster that has server certificate?

Comment: @DavorinRuševljan I need to have cert in cluster for connecting to some other resources to retrieve data

Answer (score 1):

You can add them Azure Key Vault, and reference them from your ARM template. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure#deploying-application-certificates-to-the-cluster).